# iframe issue in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl-certificate, sitefinity-5

I am accessing below URL in iframe tag.
For IE it is showing the error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage", but for all the other browser it's working fine.

[http://qaecat.burndy.com/Comergent/en/US/adirect/fci?cmd=catDisplayStyle&domProductQueryName=ks15*&OP=search&SSO_USER_NAME=PUBLIC](http://qaecat.burndy.com/Comergent/en/US/adirect/fci?cmd=catDisplayStyle&domProductQueryName=ks15%2a&OP=search&SSO_USER_NAME=PUBLIC)

When accessing the same from Chrome and Firefox it is loading fine. I am currently using IE 10.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Allen

Comment: I see you tagged the question `ssl-certificate`. Is the iframe on an `https` page?

Comment: It was SSL certificate page other than this link. So thought this might be an issue...!! Any ideas